# How to remove script and create separate js file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a timer. Currently i have it so that a script is stuck in the html to run it. I would like to separate the js into a separate file. Here is what i have so far.

**HTML**

```
 <body>
    <div id="countdown"></div>
    <div id="notifier"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startTimer() {
            userInput = document.getElementById('userTime').value;
            if (userInput.length == 0) {
                alert("Please enter a value");
            } else {
                var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
                if (!userInput.match(numericExpression)) {
                    alert("Please enter a number")
                } else {

                    function display(notifier, str) {
                        document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
                    }

                    function toMinuteAndSecond(x) {
                        return Math.floor(x / 60) + ":" + x % 60;
                    }

                    function setTimer(remain, actions) {
                        (function countdown() {
                            display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));
                            actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
                            (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
                        })();
                    }

                    setTimer(userInput, {
                        10: function() {
                            display("notifier", "Just 10 seconds to go");
                        },
                        5: function() {
                            display("notifier", "5 seconds left");
                        },
                        0: function() {
                            alert("Time is up. Please Sumbit Vote.");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    </script>Set Time Limit:
    <input type="text" id="userTime" />
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="startTimer()" />
</body>
```

Here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/grahamwalsh/0h9t65bs/

Comment: this is easy, just create script.js and in the script place you tell is what file to include `<script type="text/javascript" src="myFile.js" ></script>`

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html

Comment: every code needs to include in page. for this reason we use the same <script></script> tag, but in this time we set the `src` attribute. something like <script src="path/to/jsfile.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Make a file with the javascript code called `file.js` Then in the script tag do the following,

`<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js" ></script>`

This will make the javascript file be loaded.

Comment: Why do I need to show you a fiddle? So you can copy and paste?

Comment: Whoops, didn't see your answer when I posted mine. Please note that you are referring to a 'file.js' and a 'myFile.js' at the same time ;-)

Comment: every time i try and make a fiddle it doesnt work, it has the input but when i click the button nothing happens

Comment: @guyman why do you need to use fiddle? when you use chrome, IE, etc it will work. Also in fiddle it might not have access to external files or might need the full file path.

Comment: i would like to use fiddle so i can continue to make changes to it

Comment: @guyman what you are asking and what you want are two different things

Comment: @guyman why not just use your computer to do this on, i am very confused now.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file called `script.js` or whatever name you prefer. Make sure it's in the same directory as your html file.

Next, copy your in-html script into the script.js and change `<script type="text/javascript">` to `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">`

**EDIT:** Resulting code:

```js
function startTimer() {
  userInput = document.getElementById('userTime').value;
  if(userInput.length == 0) {
    alert("Please enter a value");
  } else {
    var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if(!userInput.match(numericExpression)) {
      alert("Please enter a number")
    } else {

      function display( notifier, str ) {
        document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
      }

      function toMinuteAndSecond( x ) {
        return Math.floor(x/60) + ":" + x%60;
      }

      function setTimer( remain, actions ) {
        (function countdown() {
           display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));         
           actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
           (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
        })();
      }

      setTimer(userInput, {
        10: function () { display("notifier", "Just 10 seconds to go"); },
        5: function () { display("notifier", "5 seconds left");        },
        0: function () { alert( "Time is up. Please Submit Vote.");       }
      }); 
      
    }  
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="countdown"></div>
  <div id="notifier"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  Set Time Limit: <input type="text" id="userTime" />
  <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="startTimer()" />
</body>
```